# ScrollView not scrolling inside absolute component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I'm trying to create a fixed `height` scrollview from a select button, in with will be able to be scrolled. Although I can't seem to make the scroll work inside a `View` component.
I have the following component:

```
<MyInput
        key={name}
        type={'select'}
        rightIcon={rightIcon}
        placeholder={"Some"}
        onChangeText={onChangedText}
        onInputFocus={onShowDropdown}
        dropdown={active && options.length > 0 && (
          <styled.Dropdown>
            <styled.Options
              keyboardShouldPersistTaps='handled'
              scrollEnabled={(options.length > 3)}
              showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              horizontal={false}>
              {options.map((item) => (
                <Option
                  key={item.id || item.text}
                  title={item.place_name || item.text}
                  selected={(item.id === highlighted) || (item.text === highlighted)}
                  onHideUnderlay={() => onHideUnderlay(item.id || item.text)}
                  onShowUnderlay={() => onShowUnderlay(item.id || item.text)}
                  onPressed={() => onSelectOption(item)} />
              ))}
            </styled.Options>
          </styled.Dropdown>
```

When I remove the `</styled.Dropdown>` the List work fine, but it won't have a fixed height.

This is the styles:

```
styles.Dropdown = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 51px;
  z-index: 30;
  background-color: ${Colors.white};
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  min-height: 56px;
  max-height: 168px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
`

styles.Options = styled.ScrollView`
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
`

styles.Option = styled.TouchableHighlight``
```

This is how it renderes (with the complete code), but it doesn't allow scrolling and the selection doesn't work:
[image]

This is how it renderes without the `<styled.DropDown>` and it works, but without a fixed height:
[image]

**OBS: IOS works fine, android doens't work**

Comment: have you found any solution to that? using ScrollView from gesture handler works for me but not if it's inside Modal